# The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I have a project where i am calling Google Cloud Storage API from Firebase Cloud FireStore API.
This is my Firebase code before adding the Google Cloud Storage dependencies.

```
 package com.example.firebase.springbootfirebasedemo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringbootFirebaseDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootFirebaseDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**This is my REST Controller**

```
package com.example.firebase.springbootfirebasedemo.controller;

import com.example.firebase.springbootfirebasedemo.entity.Review;
import com.example.firebase.springbootfirebasedemo.service.ReviewService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ReviewController {

    @Autowired
    private ReviewService reviewService;

    @PostMapping("/reviews")
    public String saveReview(@RequestBody Review review) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        return reviewService.saveReview(review);
    }

    @GetMapping("/reviews/{name}")
    public Review getReview(@PathVariable String name) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        return reviewService.getReviewDetailsByname(name);
    }

    @GetMapping("/reviews")
    public List<Review> getAllReviews() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        return reviewService.getAllReviews();
    }


    @PutMapping("/reviews")
    public String updateReview(@RequestBody Review review) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        return reviewService.updateReview(review);
    }


    @DeleteMapping("/reviews/{name}")
    public String deleteReview(@PathVariable String name) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        return reviewService.deleteReview(name);
    }
}
```

**This is my Service class**

```
package com.example.firebase.springbootfirebasedemo.service;

import com.example.firebase.springbootfirebasedemo.entity.Review;
import com.google.api.core.ApiFuture;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.Firestore;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.WriteResult;
import com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

@Service
public class ReviewService {

    private static final String COLLECTION_NAME ="Reviews";

    public String saveReview(Review review) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

       Firestore dbFirestore= FirestoreClient.getFirestore();

       ApiFuture<WriteResult> collectionApiFuture=dbFirestore.collection(COLLECTION_NAME).document(review.getName()).set(review);

       return collectionApiFuture.get().getUpdateTime().toString();

    }

    public Review getReviewDetailsByname(String name) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        Firestore dbFirestore= FirestoreClient.getFirestore();

        DocumentReference documentReference=dbFirestore.collection(COLLECTION_NAME).document(name);

        ApiFuture<DocumentSnapshot> future=documentReference.get();

        DocumentSnapshot document=future.get();

        Review review=null;
        if(document.exists()) {
         review = document.toObject(Review.class);
       return  review;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    public List<Review> getAllReviews() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        Firestore dbFirestore= FirestoreClient.getFirestore();

        Iterable<DocumentReference> documentReference=dbFirestore.collection(COLLECTION_NAME).listDocuments();
        Iterator<DocumentReference> iterator=documentReference.iterator();

        List<Review> reviewList=new ArrayList<>();
        Review review=null;

        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            DocumentReference documentReference1=iterator.next();
           ApiFuture<DocumentSnapshot> future= documentReference1.get();
           DocumentSnapshot document=future.get();

            review=document.toObject(Review.class);
           reviewList.add(review);

        }
        return reviewList;
    }


    public String updateReview(Review review) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        Firestore dbFirestore= FirestoreClient.getFirestore();

        ApiFuture<WriteResult> collectionApiFuture=dbFirestore.collection(COLLECTION_NAME).document(review.getName()).set(review);

        return collectionApiFuture.get().getUpdateTime().toString();

    }

    public String deleteReview(String name) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        Firestore dbFirestore= FirestoreClient.getFirestore();

        ApiFuture<WriteResult> collectionApiFuture=dbFirestore.collection(COLLECTION_NAME).document(name).delete();

        return "Document with Review ID "+name+" has been deleted successfully";

    }
}
```

**This is my Entity Class**

```
package com.example.firebase.springbootfirebasedemo.entity;

public class Review {

    private String name;
    private String description;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

**This is a class which reads the google service account key**

```
package com.example.firebase.springbootfirebasedemo.firebase;

import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

@Service
public class FirebaseInitialization {


    @PostConstruct
    public void initialization(){

        FileInputStream serviceAccount = null;
        try {
            serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("./serviceAccountKey.json");

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .build();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**This is my pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.firebase</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-firebase-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot-firebase-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-admin-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

So far so good. I was able to call my REST API and perform CRUD operation on my Firestore DB.
Now i need to call the Google cloud storage API from my Firebase API. For this i added the Google Cloud Storage dependencies.

**My new pom.xml after adding the Google cloud storage dependencies.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.firebase</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-firebase-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot-firebase-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud-gcp.version>2.0.4</spring-cloud-gcp.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-storage</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-admin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-gcp.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Now after adding the dependencies and running the server i was getting the following errors.

```
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.5)

2021-09-30 14:31:05.912  INFO 8540 --- [           main] .e.f.s.SpringbootFirebaseDemoApplication : Starting SpringbootFirebaseDemoApplication using Java 15.0.2 on DELL-PC with PID 8540 (D:\Downloads\Eclipse\eclipse-workspace\springboot-firebase-movie-review\target\classes started by User in D:\Downloads\Eclipse\eclipse-workspace\springboot-firebase-movie-review)
2021-09-30 14:31:05.929  INFO 8540 --- [           main] .e.f.s.SpringbootFirebaseDemoApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-09-30 14:31:07.571 ERROR 8540 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : An incompatible version [1.1.17-dev] of the Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version [1.2.14]
2021-09-30 14:31:08.343  INFO 8540 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-09-30 14:31:08.383  INFO 8540 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-09-30 14:31:08.383  INFO 8540 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.53]
2021-09-30 14:31:08.732  INFO 8540 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-09-30 14:31:08.732  INFO 8540 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2678 ms
2021-09-30 14:31:09.723  WARN 8540 --- [           main] c.g.c.s.core.DefaultCredentialsProvider  : No core credentials are set. Service-specific credentials (e.g., spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.credentials.*) should be used if your app uses services that require credentials.

java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:134) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.26.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:120) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.26.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:92) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.26.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.api.gax.core.GoogleCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(GoogleCredentialsProvider.java:67) ~[gax-1.66.0.jar:1.66.0]
    at com.google.cloud.spring.core.DefaultCredentialsProvider.<init>(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:110) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-core-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.core.GcpContextAutoConfiguration.googleCredentials(GcpContextAutoConfiguration.java:63) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at com.example.firebase.springbootfirebasedemo.SpringbootFirebaseDemoApplication.main(SpringbootFirebaseDemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]

2021-09-30 14:31:09.775  INFO 8540 --- [           main] c.g.c.s.a.c.GcpContextAutoConfiguration  : The default project ID is lustrous-braid-326814
2021-09-30 14:31:09.876  WARN 8540 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'firestoreOptions' defined in class path resource [com/google/cloud/spring/autoconfigure/firestore/GcpFirestoreAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions]: Factory method 'firestoreOptions' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to obtain credentials
2021-09-30 14:31:09.883  INFO 8540 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-09-30 14:31:09.944  INFO 8540 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-09-30 14:31:09.972 ERROR 8540 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'firestoreOptions' defined in class path resource [com/google/cloud/spring/autoconfigure/firestore/GcpFirestoreAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions]: Factory method 'firestoreOptions' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to obtain credentials
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at com.example.firebase.springbootfirebasedemo.SpringbootFirebaseDemoApplication.main(SpringbootFirebaseDemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions]: Factory method 'firestoreOptions' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to obtain credentials
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to obtain credentials
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$Builder.build(FirestoreOptions.java:212) ~[google-cloud-firestore-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.firestore.GcpFirestoreAutoConfiguration.firestoreOptions(GcpFirestoreAutoConfiguration.java:110) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:134) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.26.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:120) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.26.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:92) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.26.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.api.gax.core.GoogleCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(GoogleCredentialsProvider.java:67) ~[gax-1.66.0.jar:1.66.0]
    at com.google.cloud.spring.core.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:67) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-core-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$Builder.build(FirestoreOptions.java:210) ~[google-cloud-firestore-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

Please help.Thank you.

Comment: Where are you running your code?

Comment: @ guillaume blaquiere I am running my code on my local machine.

Comment: Try to perform a `gcloud auth application-default login`, use your credential and try again.

Comment: @guillaume blaquiere I provided the spring.cloud.gcp.project-id, spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location entries in my application.properties and its working. But i was already reading the google credentials from the FirebaseInitialization class and thought that would be sufficient. Any idea why i again have to explicitly provide the google credentials in my application.properties file.